# Only interfaces have IP address, not devices

Tags: networking, ip-address

Reading rom the book Kurose J.F., Ross K.W., Computer Networking. A Top-Down Approach, on page 338 he says "*An IP address is technically associated
with an interface, rather than with the host or router containing that interface*", thereby contradicting almost any tutorial on the internet that I have read the last days, which always associate IP addresses to devices.

He also gives this diagram as an illustration:

[image]

**My question is: How does this theory translation to a practical setup (such as a SoHo network)?**

Suppose I have a router with one physical interface connected to my ISP (the "WAN") and a physical interfaces called LAN1, LAN2, .... Since one always uses the same IP address to access my router (192.168.0.1), it seems to me that all the LAN physical interfaces actually map to the same IP address, so the router must have something like a switch (or a different layer 2 device) that groups all my different LAN devices together; is that correct?
Is there a scenario when physical LAN ports each have their own IP address?

Comment: You're missing one point here; insert one extra Ethernet-card into your computer... does it still have ONE IP-address? How would you distinguish the two Ethernet:s? Your image assumes there is just ONE Ethernet port/card in all the computers. i.e. https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/56159 behind @Gantendo's link

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56156/why-are-ip-addresses-given-to-each-interface-and-not-device-what-would-the-impl

Comment: Your router has multiple LAN ports because it has a switch built-in. More sophisticated shenanigans are possible with programmable switches though. // It’s easier to associate IP addresses with hosts because they typically would have only one interface connected to a particular network.

Comment: Traditionally Linux associates an IP address with the host, even though the IP address is "assigned" to an interface.  This can cause the [arp flux](http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-arp.html) problem. @Hannu *"How would you distinguish the two Ethernet:s?"* -- Each network interface has its  MAC address, which is what an IP address has to resolve to.

Comment: @DanielB That was what I suspected, thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Hannu What is wrong with assuming a single ethernet card at each host? My confusion anyway is more centered on what happens at the interface at the router...

Comment: Assumptions are often "wrong". The main problem is; any one of the computers may have more than one IP assigned, all that is required is at least one additional net interface, of any type. Given old serial interfaces (RS232/COM) and PPP/SLIP protocols and such, it is easy to add one.

Comment: @sawdust - with only *ONE* IP, how would that be done? ;-)